# Error while calling zooz's payment Interface, <UICustomObject 0x6d457c0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, payment

When I click on my `buyMore` button, writing below code, as written in zooz's example code given below,

```
-(IBAction)buyMore
{
    ZooZ * zooz = [ZooZ sharedInstance];
    zooz.sandbox = YES;

    zooz.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:0.8 blue:0 alpha:1];

    zooz.barButtonTintColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];

    ZooZPaymentRequest * req = [zooz createPaymentRequestWithTotal:12.1 invoiceRefNumber:@"test invoice ref-1234" delegate:self];

    req.currencyCode = @"EUR";

    req.payerDetails.firstName = @"Some";

    req.payerDetails.email = @"test@zooz.com";

    req.payerDetails.address.zip=@"01234";

    req.requireAddress = NO;

    ZooZInvoiceItem * item = [[[ZooZInvoiceItem alloc] initWithPrice:12.1 quantity:1 name:@"T-Shirt"] autorelease];//Don't forget to release/autorelease

    item.itemId = @"refId-12345678"; // optional

    [req addItem:item];

    [zooz openPayment:req forAppKey:@"951bde04-5a26-4200-a94e-34d775a1e5f9"];

}
```

I am getting Error saying...

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception NSUnknownKeyException, reason: [ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key pageControl.**

First throw call stack:

(0x1966052 0x1d4fd0a 0x1965f11 0x134c032 0x12bdf7b 0x12bdeeb 0x12d8d60 0xbcb91a 0x1967e1a 0x18d1821 0xbca46e 0xa71e2c 0xa723a9 0xa725cb 0xa72941 0xa8447d 0xa8466f 0xa8493b 0xa853df 0xa85561 0xba14ca 0x9eb301 0x1967e72 0x8cb92d 0x8d5827 0x85bfa7 0x85dea6 0x8e930c 0x9bd530 0x193a9ce 0x18d1670 0x189d4f6 0x189cdb4 0x189cccb 0x215b879 0x215b93e 0x9aca9b 0x29aa 0x28f5)

terminate called throwing an exceptionProgram ended with exit code: 0

Comment: You told me in email that you fixed this could you please post the fix

Comment: me too facing this problem can u help me please?

Answer (score 0):

```
 I think there is a problem into your XIB file.
```

Look into XIB file, have you connect any control named 'pageControl' which is not declare into  .h file.

Answer (score 0):

Please right click on the files owner and check that you are getting any warning in yellow color with any connected outlet if yes then remove it

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [Zooz Secure In app payment runtime error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12895447/zooz-secure-in-app-payment-runtime-error).
You need to follow the exact instruction in the ZooZ pdf documentation. I'm guessing you forgot adding -ObjC to "Other Linker Flags".