# Zooz Secure In app payment runtime error

Tags: iphone, crash, in-app-purchase, payment-gateway, runtime-error

I am trying to integrate ZOOZ In App payment but it is giving me error on run time. It execute my full method and then crash the application. my method is this

```
-(IBAction)buyMore{
    paymentSuccessLabel.hidden = YES;

    ZooZ * zooz = [ZooZ sharedInstance];

    zooz.sandbox = YES;

    zooz.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:0.8 blue:0 alpha:1];

    zooz.barButtonTintColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];

    ZooZPaymentRequest * req = [zooz createPaymentRequestWithTotal:12.1 invoiceRefNumber:@"test invoice ref-1234" delegate:self];

    req.currencyCode = @"EUR";

    req.payerDetails.firstName = @"Some";

    req.payerDetails.email = @"test@zooz.com";

    req.payerDetails.billingAddress.zipCode=@"01234";

    req.requireAddress = NO;

    ZooZInvoiceItem * item = [ZooZInvoiceItem invoiceItem:12.1 quantity:1 name:@"T-Shirt"];
    item.additionalDetails = @"Free 200 characters custom description";
    item.itemId = @"refId-12345678"; // optional

    [req addItem:item];

    req.invoice.additionalDetails = @"Custom invoice description text";

    [zooz openPayment:req forAppKey:@"27edd0b5-7289-4e6a-9dcb-201179701496"];

}
```

and application log on crash is this

```
Unknown class ZooZCardViewController in Interface Builder file.
Unknown class ZooZButton in Interface Builder file.
Unknown class ZooZFooterPanel in Interface Builder file.
Unknown class ZooZSpinner in Interface Builder file.
Unknown class ZooZBasePanel in Interface Builder file.
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UICustomObject 0x4c12e0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key pageControl.'
```

Kindly help me i am worried about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you did not included the ZooZ SDK library files correctly.
I suggest you will first remove all reference to ZooZ.
Also look in "framework search paths" of your target properties and make sure there is no reference there to ZooZ.

Then simply right click on your project files, choose to add new files, and select the ZooZ.embeededframework folder. (Do not mark the copy files checkbox) and do mark all the targets you want it to be added to.

There is step by step flow inside ZooZ SDK documentation PDF file, including screenshots.
Also make sure you set in the "Other Linker Flags" property of your target the "-ObjC" value